# Как в вордпресс получить даты публикаций постов по годам?

Tags: wordpress

Есть допустим обычные посты.
На странице вывода постов нужно получить все даты по годам, когда публиковались посты в виде списка и ссылки.
То есть чтобы , чтобы был список

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="test.ru/2022/">2022</a></li>//вывод всех постов за 2022
<li><a href="test.ru/2021/">2021</a></li>//вывод всех постов за 2021
</ul>
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: wp_get_archives()